# unattended installation wix read command line parameters passed to msiexec

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am writing an installer using wix. For silent installation using msiexec, i would like to provide few parameters from the commandline which i want to set to wix properties.

These properties I am using to enable/disable few features.

Can anyone please tell me how to read those command line properties passed to msiexec.
Using C++ Custom Action we read using MsiGetProperty

Thanks a lot..

Best Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 8):

To make the property available from the command line you should define it using an upper case name.  I often use a launch condition to check the properties have been passed on the command line:

```
<Property Id="PROPNAME" Admin="yes" />
<Condition Message="Public Property PROPNAME not passed">Installed or PROPNAME</Condition>
```

The Installed variable only checks for the property value on install rather than uninstall.

The command line for msiexec looks like this:

```
msiexec -i <msiname.msi> PROPNAME="PROPVALUE"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This was really helpful. A combination of all the answers on this page helped resolve my issue :)

Answer (score 6):

You should also look into the [ADDLOCAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.  You can probably simplify your problem with a command line like:

```
msiexec /i product.msi ADDLOCAL=FEATURE1,FEATURE2,FEATURE4,FEATURE5
```

Answer (score 2):

A **Feature** element can use one or more **Condition** elements as children. A feature condition can use installer properties directly in their [formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) form, for example:

```
[PROPERTY_NAME] = "value"
```

Each feature Condition element must use a [Level](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_condition.htm) attribute. In your case it can be 0 so the feature is not installed when the condition is met. Basically, you will set a condition for skipping the feature.